# How to send data from and to a database from a table view in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database

I am an newbie to obj-c programming.  I am trying to send data from a UITableView into any type of database.  I have 2 questions.
1: What type of database should I use (ex. MySQL, access)?
2: How will I transfer the database from a table view to the type of database I should use?

If my question is not direct in any way, please notify me in the contacts section.  Please do not vote down on this post.

Comment: It depends.

Is your database locally on the smartphone? Or do you need to send the data to some kind of server? 
Does the server support any type of web service or api?

Comment: Anyway, this question is far to broad for SO.

Comment: I just want to save the data.  Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: "Please do not vote down this post." While I appreciate you don't want it down-voted, the burden rests on you to write questions that don't deserve a down-voted like this one does. You should clarify (are you talking about database on iOS device or some server database) and illustrate the research you've done (because these questions have been asked and answered many, many times here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Assuming you're talking about how to interface with remote database, I'd refer you to Wenderlich's companion pieces [How To Write an iOS App that Uses a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service) and [How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: What type of database should I use (ex. MySQL, access)?

If you want local database go for CoreData. If you want shared database then any other database will go like MySql, Oracle, etc.

> 2: How will I transfer the database from a table view to the type of database I should use?

For CoreData you have managedObject classes and few others to save, retrieve etc.
For other databases you need to use webservice calls then the server will connect your app to database.

NOTE: TableView doesn't contain any data. Data are contained by some model objects, you need to store the data in array, dictionary, strings or any other form and send these data via webservice (json, xml, soap) then it will handle.

Comment: When I said data, I meant the array (mutable) behind the table

Comment: cool. then you know how and what to send.

Answer (score 0):

For the following scenario you can use Different database

1. Store/Retrive data to/from within Application 
   User Coredata or SQlite

   [CORE DATA](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

   [SQLITE TUTORIAL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm)
2. You need to store/retrive big size of datas
   You can use Web Service you achieve the goal.

   Web service is developed by many programming languages.you will use any type of web service to achieve this goal.

   **Note: Its only work with Internet connectivity**